# t-sql JOIN where clause best practice

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, relational-database

I have below query :

```
SELECT s.LogonId "StaffId" FROM [dbo].[SQMap] sq
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Staff] s ON s.Id = sq.StaffId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Queue] q ON q.Id = sq.QueueId
WHERE sq.QueueId = @queueId AND q.IsAuto = 1
```

I was asked to change the query to add more conditions to where clause

```
WHERE sq.QueueId = @queueId 
AND q.Id = @queueId
AND q.IsAutoAssigned = 1
```

I was wondering if **q.Id = @queueId** is really required. I have seen many queries with such redundant conditions. Are these really required. What's the best practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time I have seen duplicate conditions intentionally used to good affect have been in attempts to get the query optimizer to come up with better plans. But that was years ago on a different relational database. With modern optimizers it will be rare that adding the duplicate condition will change the plan one bit. The way to see would be to run both queries and see if the plans differ.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it's required., If the query does not include the specific `queueId` you want to filter on (assuming you want to filter on it), then all records, for all QueueIds will be returned.

But it does not have to be there twice, and since the join condition restricts the output to include only those records from `dbo.Queue` that match the `queueId` from `dbo.SQLMap` placing the where predicate on either one will restrict both tables.

Comment: The conditions of `sq.QueueId = @QueueId` and `q.Id = sq.QueueId` make `q.Id = @queueId` redundant.